# Spring Boot doesnt bind to Tomcat port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am trying to deploy a `war` Spring Boot project into a Tomcat server that has other projects bound to some ports. When I am deploying the new `war` project, the services don't seem to be bound to the port `8082` that has been assigned from Spring Boot `application-properties`.

First of all, I added the new port `8082` on `server.xml`

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="-1"
           redirectPort="8443" /> //That was already specified

<Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" /> //My addition
```

Then with `netstat -plnt` I saw the port is available

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8082                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

By going to `/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/webapps` it seems that my new `war` application has been deployed.

Application Logs doesn't show any errors or exceptions and the Spring Boot application seems to run. Here are the full logs from Spring: https://pastebin.com/nX04gjE3

When I am trying to test the services with

`wget http://localhost:8082/services/test`

I get the following

```
--2019-06-10 09:49:56--  http://localhost:8082/services/test
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8082... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-06-10 09:49:56 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

After every change, I restart apache of course. 
This is a deployed server and not on the local machine, every change I made is with putty and winscp.

`ServicesApplication.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServicesApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ServicesApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`application-properties`

```
server.port=8082
http.port=8082


logging.file = /opt/logs/services.log


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X/name?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

**Edit:** I don't need the app to run on `8082` I can accept answers for the same port for the others `8080`.

Comment: There may be issue with API URL.  Check for base Url. http://localhost:8082/services/test

Comment: It works locally

Comment: How does your war was called ? Is it services.war ?

Comment: Yes and tomcat seems to extract the folder correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to specify a new  section in the `server.xml` just for that app if you want to run it under a specific port apart from another being also available:

```
 <Server>
  <Service name="commonservice">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="-1"
           redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine><Host name="commonhost">
          <Context path="/commonwebab"/>     
    </Host></Engine>
  </Service>
  <Service name="springservice">
    <Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="8444" />
    <Engine><Host name="springhost">
      <Context path="/springapp"/>
    </Host></Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Spring Boot wise, make sure your normal Main class extends:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer
```

Comment: I must say that I don't really need for the app to run on a new port. I changed it because I thought there was issues with the other apps. As for your suggestion, I don't believe I can implement it because the Service name is binded to `Catalina` and I believe I shouldn't add a new one. I edited my post that I don't need for it to be specified on a new port, I will take answers for even the same port `8080`