# Spring Boot app in Docker receives: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, heroku

I have a Spring Boot app in Docker that runs on Heroku.

Recently, after updating Tomcat to 10.1.0-M10, I started getting this error:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within
> 60 seconds of launch

The immediate thought of downgrading to lower versions doesn't work due to vulnerabilities in the earlier versions. I have checked possible causes and found Tomcat [binding port issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521792/spring-boot-doesnt-bind-to-tomcat-port).

I cannot set up fixed config for different ports as I am deploying to Heroku and dependent on their random ports.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11
ENV PORT=$PORT
COPY /target/app.jar /app.jar
CMD java -Xms256m -Xmx512m \
    -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true \
    -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom \
    -Dserver.port=$PORT \
    -jar /app.jar
```

What is the way to solve it? Is there anything I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

There are more logs from Heroku:

```
Feb 22 12:50:16 integration-test app/web.1 2022-02-22 20:50:16.057 [main] INFO  c.g.s.z.ApplicationKt - Started ApplicationKt in 8.09 seconds (JVM running for 9.062)
Feb 22 12:50:16 integration-test app/web.1 2022-02-22 20:50:16.060 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean - Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
Feb 22 12:50:16 integration-test app/web.1 2022-02-22 20:50:16.063 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean - Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
Feb 22 12:51:06 integration-test heroku/web.1 Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Comment: It's a strange message you are receiving because it states $PORT instead de port value. Do you have a .env that is configuring PORT variable or passing when you do a docker build?

Comment: I do it via heroku CLI:
`heroku container:login` | `heroku container:push -a app web` | `heroku container:release -a app web`

Previously, I didn't need to explicitly set $PORT in here.

Comment: @pringi Any idea on this? I still cannot find a solution to this, and it's pretty problematic to debug. To complement my previous point, I am 100% sure that the port is passed to app.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that wasn't perfect but seemed to work for me.

- Downgraded Spring Boot from `2.6.3` to `2.6.1`
- Downgraded Tomcat from `10.X.X` to `9.X.X`
- Removed dev tools dependencies

I think the two latest did the magic. Dev tools stopped asking for an extra port in the test/prod environment. Tomcat bound the port in the version `9.X.X` but not in `10.X.X`.

Even though I found the solution, I don't know why it behaved like this, and it isn't perfect security-wise.

Answer (score 0):

from the error message it seems that `$PORT` is not resolved to any environment variable.

deploying to heroku you must use `.env` file to define env vars (you can't use `docker run -e PORT=1234`) [see documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#get-the-port-from-the-environment-variable)

> When you use heroku locally, you can set config vars in a .env file. When heroku local is run .env is read and each name/value pair is set in the environment. You can use this same .env file when using Docker: `docker run -p 5000:5000 --env-file .env <image-name>`